# vb.net backgroundworker with mysql reader to multiple textboxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, backgroundworker

I want to run a BGW every 1 sec to run a mySQL query and fill the different textboxes in my form.

This is my functioning query:

```
Public Sub AnrufAutoLaden()
    Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT   CCE.callerid Telefonnummer,
                                    date_format(CCE.datetime_init, '%d-%m-%Y') Datum,
                                    TIME_FORMAT(CCE.datetime_init, '%H:%i') Uhrzeit,
                                    A.Alias Agent, 
                                    CONVERT( CAST(CE.name AS BINARY) USING UTF8) Kunde          
                            FROM call_center.current_call_entry CCE, call_center.agent A, call_center.campaign_entry CE
                            where CE.estatus = 'A'
                            AND A.estatus = 'A'
                            AND A.id = CCE.id_agent
                            AND CE.id_queue_call_entry = CCE.id_queue_call_entry
                            AND A.name ='" & LabelUsername.Text & "';"
    Dim mycmdIDForm As New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
    Dim rdr As Object = mycmdIDForm.ExecuteReader()
    If rdr.read() Then
        TBDashBCallerID.Text = rdr("Telefonnummer").ToString
        TBDashBDatum.Text = rdr("Datum").ToString
        TBDashBZeit.Text = rdr("Uhrzeit").ToString
        TBDashBAgent.Text = rdr("Agent").ToString
        TBDashBKunde.Text = rdr("Kunde").ToString
    End If
    mysqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

I was able to do it but for every textbox I need to run a separate BGW, like this:

```
Private Sub BGWAdminInfoV_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWAdminInfoV.DoWork
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    If BGWAdminInfoV.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim countquery2 As String = "SELECT     CCE.callerid Telefonnummer          
                            FROM call_center.current_call_entry CCE, call_center.agent A, call_center.campaign_entry CE
                            where CE.estatus = 'A'
                            AND A.estatus = 'A'
                            AND A.id = CCE.id_agent
                            AND CE.id_queue_call_entry = CCE.id_queue_call_entry
                            AND A.name ='" & LabelUsername.Text & "';;"
        Dim countcmd2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(countquery2, mysqlconn)
        e.Result = countcmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        mysqlconn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub BGWAdminInfoV_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGWAdminInfoV.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
    Else
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() TBDashBCallerID.Text = e.Result))
        BGWAdminInfoV.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```

But is there a way to do it with one BGW. So that I run one BGW every 1 second and return all five values to all five textboxes:

```
TBDashBCallerID.Text
TBDashBDatum.Text
TBDashBZeit.Text 
TBDashBAgent.Text
TBDashBKunde.Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why switch from `ExecuteReader` to `ExecuteScalar`? Just use the same ADO.NET code you already have but, instead of putting the values into the `TextBoxes`, put them into the properties of an object or the elements of an array. You then get all the values out of that same object/array in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler and populate all the `TextBoxes`.

Kick things off like this:

```vb
BGWAdminInfoV.RunWorkerAsync(LabelUsername.Text)
```

and then do this:

```vb
Private Sub BGWAdminInfoV_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWAdminInfoV.DoWork
    Dim mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT   CCE.callerid Telefonnummer,
                                date_format(CCE.datetime_init, '%d-%m-%Y') Datum,
                                TIME_FORMAT(CCE.datetime_init, '%H:%i') Uhrzeit,
                                A.Alias Agent, 
                                CONVERT( CAST(CE.name AS BINARY) USING UTF8) Kunde          
                        FROM call_center.current_call_entry CCE, call_center.agent A, call_center.campaign_entry CE
                        where CE.estatus = 'A'
                        AND A.estatus = 'A'
                        AND A.id = CCE.id_agent
                        AND CE.id_queue_call_entry = CCE.id_queue_call_entry
                        AND A.name = @name;"
    Dim mycmdIDForm As New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
    mycmdIDForm.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = e.Argument
    Dim rdr As Object = mycmdIDForm.ExecuteReader()
    Dim result As String()
    If rdr.Read() Then
        result = {rdr("Telefonnummer").ToString(),
                  rdr("Datum").ToString(),
                  rdr("Uhrzeit").ToString(),
                  rdr("Agent").ToString(),
                  rdr("Kunde").ToString()}
    End If
    mysqlconn.Close()

    e.Result = result
End Sub

Private Sub BGWAdminInfoV_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGWAdminInfoV.RunWorkerCompleted
    If Not e.Cancelled AndAlso e.Result IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim result = DirectCast(e.Result, String())

        TBDashBCallerID.Text = result(0)
        TBDashBDatum.Text = result(1)
        TBDashBZeit.Text = result(2)
        TBDashBAgent.Text = result(3)
        TBDashBKunde.Text = result(4)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a great explanation, and it is working.
I have made some minor changes because I need the BGW to work automatically every 1 second. So I put in the "DOWORK" section the "Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)" and in the "RunkWorkerCompleted" section the again running WorkerAsync: "BGWAnrufeAutoLaden.RunWorkerAsync(LabelUsername.Text)".
And now it works perfect.

Comment: That's not the way to run the BGW every second. Instead, you should add a `Timer`, set the `Interval` to 1000 and call `RunWorkerAsync` in the `Tick` event handler. If you want a second between the completion of one cycle and the beginning of the next, rather than between the beginning of each, then you should `Stop` the `Timer` before calling `RunWorkerAsync` and `Start` it again in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Comment: ok, I thought it's easier like this to do it, but if it is not meant to work like this, I will do it with the Timer. THX for the suggestion.